# How to pause WLAN interface in linux?

Tags: linux, network-interface, router, systemd-networkd, dd-wrt

I am working on a project with a Wi-Fi router (TP-Link) installed with dd-wrt firmware.  A latop is directly connected over eth port with the router (as an adminsitrator who controls the router over telnet). There is also a user who is connected to the router wirelessly (ussing SSID, as any user would do to use the internet).

Let's say the user is continuously downloading content. Now, I require to make this wlan interface (in my case ath0 through which the user is connected to) pause every 30 seconds for 2 second period, and then resume the traffic again.

It is not a good idea to make the inteface down, as it will take some time to reconnect, and resume traffic (more than 6-7 sec as checked). Is there any way by which I can pause the traffic on the interface rathen than shutting it down completely ? Or what are the options by which the link can come live at its earliest ?

Comment: That is a very strange requirement, what problem are you solving?

Comment: Something can be cobbled together with enabling and disabling IPv4 forwarding, but depending on how nicely you do that, different things break on the client. It's never a good solution if you want to offer an internet access. Could you explain what what periodic 2s downtime is good for? Maybe we can help with that!

Comment: @MarcusMüller in this 2 sec wi-fi off period, another wireless sensing device (low power and on the same 2.4 GHz band) will operate (not wifi, i.e. No CSMA/CA or energy detection is available) . The off period is required so there wont be any intererence between these two network

Comment: Oh, that's a hard problem! Works temporarily moving the network to a different wifi channel work? Or does the sensing incorporate the full band?

Comment: Note that the other device is in violation of requirements for unlicensed operation of it takes no notice of other systems already operating ( unless it fulfills strict duty cycle requirements, but it would seem it doesn't do!)

Comment: Sensing device will use only 2 MHz, but I'm trying to solve with the wifi coinsiding with this channel :-!

Comment: Yeah so make the access point instruct all stations to switch to a different channel before, and switch back after. If one side just unilaterally stops communicating, the other will send packets at high power assuming packets got lost.

Comment: But the problem here really is the non-conforming secondary device. There's no way to guarantee collision freedom in an unlicensed band. You cannot solve the coexistence problem, you can only hope you're the only one using that channel. Bluetooth, other networks, and a bunch of other protocols will not care and use that channel as soon as your wifi stops using it.